# Store the passphrase of encrypted disk in /etc/crypttab encrypted

Tags: configuration, security, encryption, automount

I'm wondering, if I can store the passphrase of an encrypted disk in /etc/crypttab encrypted - and only possible to decrypt that by that OS, where I created. Is it possible?

(because, I want auto mount the disk after a restart, but I don't want to allow to read that password from the file with a simple live disk)

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can read stored passwords from a live disk. This may not be necessary.

Comment: But then you'd have to store a passphrase to decrypt that passphrase somewhere :) And you can't store that second passphrase encrypted unless you willing to create a third passphrase to encrypt the second passphrase, and so on. That's the thing with encryption - unless the secret is stored outside of the system (in your head) you have to just dump it there in plain text and just make sure nobody has physical access to the system.

Comment: @TomBrossman - we can, if I store it in a file read only by root, they put in a live disc, and mount the HDD, and they are root than.

Comment: @Sergey - can every Linux machine create unique hash? That they can only decrypt with their unique something... - like in ZNC... we have to generate the pw hash, and when I tried to move the config to other computer, the pw didn't work. How did it do it?

Comment: Just use Disk Utility to format the disk as an encrypted partition, then mount it in Nautilus. Choose 'remember forever' and the key gets saved in Seahorse and can't be read from a live disk. This is simple and secure. Maybe I'm not understanding the goal here, it seems needlessly complex. Are we talking about /home here or a separate SATA or USB drive?

Comment: @TomBrossman, to be honest, it will a CLI debian. I don't know, if there is CLI Seahorse. Is there?

Comment: @B.Roland: If every machine had a unique hash, an intruder would just need to copy the file and the hash instead of just the file :) There is NO solution to the problem except storing a secret outside of the system.

Answer (score 3):

First, add a keyfile to each encrypted volume then, simply edit your crypttab [/etc/crypttab] to include your extra encrypted volumes.

### Make a key:

> The keyfile can be of arbitrary content and size. We will generate a
>   random temporary keyfile of 2048 bytes:
>
> #### dd if=/dev/urandom of=secretkey bs=512 count=4

### Add a key

> #### cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda2 secretkey
>
> > Enter any LUKS passphrase:
> >
> > key slot 0 unlocked.
> >
> > Command successful.

### Add to crypttab:

```
label      UUID=#       keyfile-location     luks
```

Comment: Hm, so I can't avoid the theft of the passphrase. If someone opens the HDD of the computer, he can easily recover the key, and that's all... Any other solution?

Comment: Simply encrypt your root drive. no point in encrypting just one of your drives. /boot itself has to remain unencrypted but can easily be placed on a thumbdrive. So long as your keyfiles remain on an encrypted system and are stored on an encrypted drive, the only way to get them is physical access to the machine. Basically there is nothing you can do about a system left on and decrypted that someone can access. Limit physical access and turn the machine off (especially with laptops) and your fine.