# How to make dm-crypt ask for password only once?

Tags: encryption

I have several raw volumes with cryptsetup-luks containers filled with my data and ubuntu asks me for password for every encrypted volume even when passwords are the same.

How to make it to try the same password for each volume and when it fails- then ask again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly my answer here will help i.e.

rather than duplicate the answer I have added a link.

- https://askubuntu.com/a/213398/14356